# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify'

Tags: python, ssl, jenkins, https, jenkins-api

Currently, I am trying to make a Jenkins API request with Python; however, I am getting in return a certificate error.

In order to bypass this (and take the easy way out) I'm calling a jenkins request with the parameter ssl_verify = False.

But the program still returns

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_verify'
```

The code looks something like this:

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins(URL, username, password, ssl_verify=False)
```

I also tried the following call:

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins(URL, requester=Requester(username, password, baseurl, ssl_verify=False)
```

For the latter, I receive the error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requester'
```

I know declaring ssl verify = False is not the safest option but I'm trying to make this easy.

Any help or answers will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: which version of python? Which package and version of jenkin you have used?

Comment: python 2.7.5     ;     jenkins 2.68

Comment: Which python jenkin packges you are using? python-jenkin? jenkin-webapi? There are so many of them

Comment: You're not lying... the version is jenkinsapi-0.3.4 six-1.11.0    --- just updated to the latest version of this

Comment: Pretty sure you have another jenkins packages installed which has a different  constructor. Try `pip list` to see if there is another jenkins package

Comment: Another possibility is you might have a local module by the same name which shadowed the `jenkinsapi` package